# loading data from indexeddb in segments

Tags: javascript, html, indexeddb

I am working with `IndexedDB` and I have a database with about 4000 records. I am trying to load small chucks of records at a time. Something similar to the infinite scrolling you see on your twitter feed. I've tried to Google this and found no code examples, but came across the advance method. I tried to use that, but still no success. The browser loaded all the records at once. How do I make it so I am only loading small amounts of records at a time?

```
var openRequest = indexedDB.open("USA", 1);

        openRequest.onsuccess = function (e) {
            var db = e.target.result;
            var transaction = db.transaction(["Male"], "readonly");
            var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("Male");
            var cursor = objectStore.openCursor();

            cursor.onsuccess = function (e) {
                var res = e.target.result;

                if (res) {
                    res.advance(25);
                    res.continue();
                    console.log(res.value);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBKeyRange.bound

Answer (score 1):

The res.advance(25) will skip 25 rows but it will still load the rest. I changed your code + added some comments. You might want to use something like this:

```
var openRequest = indexedDB.open("USA", 1);

openRequest.onsuccess = function (e) {
    var db = e.target.result;
    var transaction = db.transaction(["Male"], "readonly");
    var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("Male");
    var cursor = objectStore.openCursor();
    var results = null; // variable to store the results
    var startIndex = 25,
        maxResults = 25;

    cursor.onsuccess = function (e) {
        var res = e.target.result;

        if (res) {
            if (!results) {
                results = [];
                // skip rows, but only the first time
                res.advance(startIndex);
            } else {
                results.push(res.value)
                // We don't have 25 results yet, continue to load a next one
                if(results.length < maxResults) {
                    res.continue();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    transaction.oncomplete = function() { 
        // maxResults loaded or maybe it was the last page so it might not be full
        console.log(results);
    }
}
```

The below example is a lot more simple and works with autoincrement, but the pages are only full when results aren't deleted (not full code, but it's all about the IDBKeyRange.bound(0, 25))

```
var cursor = objectStore.openCursor(IDBKeyRange.bound(0, 25));
var results = [];
cursor.onsuccess = function (e) {
    var res = e.target.result;
    if (res) {
        results.push(res.value)
    }
}
transaction.oncomplete = function() { 
    console.log(results);
}
```